# Does Branch.io work in expo managed workflow?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using Expo SDK version 36.0.0.I am trying to implement deep linking using Branch.io. I've configured branch for android. But branch.subscribe() is not getting triggered. If anybody has come across with this issue,please help.

Comment: Could you make sure you are calling subscribe first before reading the link params?

Comment: I am following [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/branch/) documentation. I have added Branch.subscribe() in componentDidMount() method. When I run the app via expo client, I get this error  :  null is not an object (evaluating RNBranch.STANDARD_EVENT_ADD_TO_CART.  When I try running it as standalone app,it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

For me RNBranch only worked in production, in the development environment it always gives the error.
So, for testing purposes, I needed to do a standalone build and installed directly on the device. See the docs https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/